# Messy order on items fetched

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, fetch

I'm trying to display 10 pokemons on the html... What I'm getting sometimes is a messy order on the final result. Like pokemon with id=5 appears 2nd and so on .

I assume my error comes from some asynchronism between the functions calls.

I'm kinda new on async functions so don't judge me bad on it lol...

So my code goes like this:

```
pokemonAPI = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=0&limit=10";

async function getPokemonList(url){
    let resp = await fetch(url);
    if (resp.ok){
        let list = await resp.json();
        list.results.forEach(pokemon => {
            getPokemonData(pokemon.url);
        });
    }
}
```

Then getPokemonData function:

```
async function getPokemonData (url){
    let resp = await fetch(url);
    if (!resp.ok){
        throw new Error(`HTTP error!, fetching pokemon data. Status: ${resp.status}`);
    }
    let data = await resp.json();
    fillContent(data);
}
```

**fillContent** function uses innerHTML to add a new card to my container div element.

Finally the result (not always) looks like this: [Display error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiUAy.jpg)

Any suggestions on where I'm getting it wrong?

Comment: In the `list.results.forEach` function, you start requesting all pokemons without waiting for the response. The responses come in at a different speed and whichever comes first gets handled first (more precise, the `await fetch(url)` finishes first and continues). You could take a look at [for await ... of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of) instead of `forEach`

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: The problem is that you are calling fillcontent inside the asyncronous function, so it is posible that the 5th pokemon fetch URL is done before the 2nd one. To avoid this behavior you can extract that fillContent function and apply it to the list itself in get pokemonList

Comment: If you want a more efficient solution (and the API only provides an endpoint for single pokemons), I'd suggest to (1) start requesting all pokemons, (2) wait for all requests to finish and (3) insert the html for all of them. You could do that with `Promise.all` but that is slightly more complex

Comment: Nvm the first comment, I was a bit confused. A simple for loop instead of `forEach` and `await getPokemonData(pokemon.url)` should do the trick

Comment: @A_A **it worked**, thank you. I was trying to put an await on the `getPokemonData(pokemon.url)` but getting _SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules_. And didn't understood why

Comment: @GabrielZerbino Good to hear. You can write your solution as an answer and accept it, so future readers have it easier, and no one tries to solve the solved problem :)

Comment: @A_A Not `for await … of`, that's only for asynchronous generators. A plain `for … of` will do.

Comment: Can you show us what `fillContent` does? If you create the (empty) DOM nodes during the `forEach` loop, and then call `fillContent` with the respective id, they would show up in the right order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@A_A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6548154/a-a) for the help

> Nvm the first comment, I was a bit confused. A simple for loop instead
> of forEach and await getPokemonData(pokemon.url) should do the trick

So actually I was calling my function `getPokemonData(pokemon.url)` one after another in a `forEach`  without waiting for it to finish fetching the url I was sending.

```
for (let pokemon of list.results){
   await getPokemonData(pokemon.url);
}
```

Changing it to a simple loop and waiting for my function to end solved it